# Synonym for "psychic hour"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

This is the full passage from  :
The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren

> the spirit comes across as a large undifferentiated black mass that is easily visible on the rare occasions when it is seen during the day though it will more likely be witnessed during the psychic hours of night.

So I know the meaning of psychic hour , but is there a word that could be a synonym for it ?

Comment: In what context do you plan to use the synonym? Are you looking for a word for the hours between 9pm and 6am or just a generic term for a period of the night when various supernatural things allegedly occur?

Comment: I think both of them could be the psychic hours, because these supernatural phenomena happen between those hours and peak at 3 am .

Comment: *"So I know the meaning of psychic hou**r**"*, which is not related to psychic hour**s**. There is no synonym for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two similar terms are given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witching_hour)

> In folklore, the **witching hour** or **devil's hour** is a time of night that is associated with supernatural events, whereby witches, demons and ghosts are thought to appear and be at their most powerful. Definitions vary, and include the hour immediately after midnight, and the time between 3:00 am and 4:00 am.

Shakespeare has Hamlet begin one of his soliloquies:

> ’Tis now the very **witching time** of night,
> When churchyards yawn, and hell itself breathes out
> Contagion to this world. Now could I drink hot blood
> And do such bitter business as the day
> Would quake to look on.…